# How to change value of one column in DataTables in jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, api, datatables

I'm making one jQuery DataTable, in that I need to make some changes before rendering the data table.

Sample data:

```
[{
  "time": "2018-07-18T15:16:10.557Z",
  "data": "AQAAH"
}, {
  "time": "2018-07-18T15:13:10.557Z",
  "data": "AQAAH"
}]
```

I want to change the value of the data column before rendering onto the DataTable, like data:

> AQAAH to 0100001c

I want to convert the data from `base64` to `hex`, then I want to render in the DataTable.

Code:

```
function getddata() {
  var xmlhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
  xmlhttp.onreadystatechange = function() {
    if (xmlhttp.readyState == 4 && xmlhttp.status == 200) {
      var Readings = JSON.parse(xmlhttp.responseText);

      $(document).ready(function() {
        $('#example').DataTable({
          data: Readings,
          columns: [{
            "data": "time"
          }, {
            "data": "data"
          }]
        });
      });
      //data table code -close
    }
  };
  xmlhttp.open("GET", "url", true);
  xmlhttp.setRequestHeader("Content-type", "Application/json");
  xmlhttp.send();
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `column.render` option in DataTables. Check the [documentation](https://datatables.net/examples/advanced_init/column_render.html) for more details.

```
$('#example').DataTable({
  data: Readings,
  columns: [{
    "data": "time"
  }, {
    "data": "data"
  }],
  columnDefs: [{
      "render": function ( data, type, row ) {
        // here you can convert data from base64 to hex and return it
        return data
      },
      "targets": 1
   }]
});
```

I believe this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39460182/decode-base64-to-hexadecimal-string-with-javascript/39460839) will help you in the conversion.

Comment: i have used column.render and able to convert base 64 to hex.

Comment: @krishnamohan yes you can do the conversion inside the render function.