# Decode Base64 string

Tags: javascript, base64, decode, encode

I am currently working on a custom SAPUI5 app. I would like to make a service call, which expects the Guid in a different format than it is currently available.

An example:

- Available (base64): `QvLAUUzUCZbhAAAAjSS2iA==`
- As it should be (hexadecimal): `42F2C0514CD40996E10000008D24B688`

I have not found an online decoder, which could produce the desired result, however, I was able to encode the guid `42F2C0514CD40996E10000008D24B` to `QvLAUUzUCZbhAAAAjss2iA==` with the SAP ABAP standard function module `HTTP_BASE64_ENCODE`. With the usual online encoders, however, I got a different result.

How can I decode the encoded guid with JavaScript so that it has the desired format?

Comment: `atob("QvLAUUzUCZbhAAAAjSS2iA==").replace(/[^]/g, c => c.charCodeAt(0).toString(16))`

Comment: Hi Thomas. Thank you for the answer, this looks already quite good! There is only something wrong with zeros. Your function returns "42f2c0514cd4996e10008d24b688" and it should be "42F2C0514CD4**0**996E1000**000**8D24B688". I marked the missing ones bold. It seems like they get lost...

Comment: And could you please tell me something about the meaning of the regex and charCodeAt? Thank you!

Comment: The regex is replacing all characters for its hexadecimal representation.

Comment: For your information, this online decoder/encoder gives the right result: https://paulschou.com/tools/xlate/

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Decode Base64 to Hexadecimal string with javascript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39460182/decode-base64-to-hexadecimal-string-with-javascript)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The string is in hexadecimal format you will have to convert it.

First you convert the string to binary (atob > charCodeAt) and then using the toString(16) you get the hex.

I will not post the code, since its already explained
[Decode Base64 to Hexadecimal string with javascript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39460182/decode-base64-to-hexadecimal-string-with-javascript/39460839)