# How to convert Postgres bytea to base64 string

Tags: javascript, postgresql, base64, hasura, bytea

I have a base64 image that I am trying to save in a Postgres database (using Hasura). The field is of type `bytea` I am not sure how to save this data to the field.

I tried passing `data:image/png;base64,sisodjodo...` to the field, and it saves it like this: `\x6956424f5277304b47676f414141414...`

When I get it back it doesn't seem to come back in the same manner that it was saved.

```js
// Query the database and save resulting object
const user = {
  avatar: '\x6956424f5277304b47676f414141414...'
}
user.avatar = btoa(user.avatar);
console.log(user.avatar);
// Prints: XHg2OTU2NDI0ZjUyNzczMDRiNDc2NzZmNDE0MTQxNDE0Z...
```

Comment: Whatever `btoa()` is, it's not treating your `'\x6956424f5277304b47676f41414141'` as a binary.  It is instead treating it like the string representation of `\x6956424f5277304b47676f41414141`.  I don't do javascript since it's the devil's native tongue, but I was able to duplicate your output using `select encode('\\x6956424f5277304b47676f41414141', 'base64');` in a language not of darkness.

Comment: Use `text`, not `bytea`, for a base64 encoded image.

Comment: @MikeOrganek `btoa()` creates a Base64-encoded ASCII string from a binary string (i.e., a String object in which each character in the string is treated as a byte of binary data).

Comment: @LaurenzAlbe I am not sure I can I am not the database administrator, so I don't have the ability to change it.

Comment: That representation you see is the hex string representation of the binary data stored in the column.  Whatever you are using to retrieve it from the database is treating it as a string instead of a byte array.  Can you include the code you use to query PostgreSQL?

Comment: The query that is used is generated by Hasura, so I assume that they are selecting it as a string like you say. I did however find a way to make the column a text column through the Hasura interface like @LaurenzAlbe had mentioned.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Postgres `bytea` fields must be entered in one of two formats, the simplest one being [hex](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/11/datatype-binary.html#id-1.5.7.12.9). This format looks like `\x[your byte string in hex]`

So, suppose you have a table called `things` with a `bytea` column `field`, you can insert a new row with the byte string `010101` like this:

```
mutation {
  insert_things_one(object: {
    field: "\\x010101"
  }) {
    field
  }
}
```

The result will be:

```
{
  "data": {
    "insert_thing_one": {
      "field": "\\x010101"
    }
  }
}
```

Note in GraphQL you have to escape the `\`. You can verify in SQL that it's stored correctly:

```
> select * from things;

field
\x010101
```

If you want to store a base64-encoded byte string per your question, you need to strip off the leading `data:image/png;base64,` and then encode the base64 string as hex in whatever language you're using. In JS: [Decode Base64 to Hexadecimal string with javascript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39460182/decode-base64-to-hexadecimal-string-with-javascript)

---

PS. I would not recommend using text fields to store base64 encoded strings. It will cost you a lot more storage than necessary. Just re-encode into hex, per my answer above.

Comment: Okay great! It is saving now, but how to I convert it back to a base64 when doing a query with Hasura?

Comment: NVM: `btoa(user.avatar.replace('\\x', '').match(/\w{2}/g).map(a => String.fromCharCode(parseInt(a, 16))).join(""))`

Comment: Yep, exactly! 