# How to implement string conversion Base64 to Hex in java equal to given JS implementation?

Tags: java

I'm trying to implement a string conversion from Base64 to Hex, that must yield the same results as
[this website](https://base64.guru/converter/decode/hex). Which means for example (Base64: *bACAAAAAAAA=*) is deconverted to (Hex: *6c00800000000000*). [This implementation in *Javascript*](https://stackoverflow.com/a/39460727/4958965) yields the correct output. So I tried to implement the equivalent in *Java*:

```
    private static String base64ToHex(String input) {
        byte[] raw = Base64.getDecoder().decode(input.getBytes());
        String result = "";
        for (int i = 0; i < raw.length; i++) {
            String hex = Integer.toString(raw[i], 16);
            result += (hex.length() == 2 ? hex : '0' + hex);
        }
        return result.toUpperCase();
    }
```

Unfortunately this does not give the required output. So could you please give me hint about what I am missing?

Comment: The whole point of Base64 is to avoid converting raw binary into a string as it tends to corrupt the data. i..e don't do what you did on the first line. use a `byte[]` instead.

Comment: For sure I did not understand you correctly; it still isn't the desired output

Comment: On one hand you wrote that you want to decode, on the other hand you encode: `Base64.getEncoder()`

Comment: You got a point there

Comment: The output is still *6C000-800000000000*

Comment: @BenjaminZach check now.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try below - You need to decode, not encode. Consider only value from decoded, ignore sign part. i.e take only absolute value, using Math.abs().

```
           private static String base64ToHex(String input) {
            byte[] raw = Base64.getDecoder().decode(input.getBytes());
            String result = "";
             for (int i = 0; i < raw.length; i++) {
                  String hex = Integer.toString(Math.abs(raw[i]), 16);
                  result += (hex.length() == 2 ? hex : '0' + hex);
              }
            return result.toUpperCase();
          }
```

Comment: Output is *6C000-800000000000*, how to get rid of the additional *0-*?

Comment: @BenjaminZach This was because negative value passed to Integer.toString(). Updated code. Check now.

Answer (score 2):

```
     private static String base64ToHex(String input) {
         byte[] raw = Base64.getDecoder().decode(
                input.getBytes(StandardCharsets.US_ASCII));
         StringBuilder result = new StringBuilder(raw.length * 2);
         for  (byte b : raw) {
              result.append(String.format("%02X", b & 0xFF));
         }
         return result.toString();
     }
```

The problem is that java `byte` is *signed*, hence the masking `& 0xFF`.