# Decoding the given string to know the original string and number of characters

Tags: javascript, algorithm, encoding, base64, decode

I have the following base 64 string:

```
/d4OjQAGAgJvToLbkeZ1rQ==
```

when I try to decode this it gives some non readable characters `ýÞoN‚Û‘æu­`

How can I decode such that the decoded value makes some sense? I want to know the number of characters involved in creating the above base64. I actually want to know the string that created this encoding.

I used javascript's `atob` function to decode.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Decode Base64 to Hexadecimal string with javascript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39460182/decode-base64-to-hexadecimal-string-with-javascript)

Comment: What is the source of your encoded data?

Comment: @trincot A URL `..m.aspx?formid=/d4OjQAGAgJvToLbkeZ1rQ==`

Comment: Who produces this URL?

Comment: @trincot Some external application

Comment: @trincot Any idea?

Comment: There is not enough information. It seems like you are guessing it is Base64 and guessing it should decode into a readable string. If not, then you have not provided all information.

Answer (score -2):

May be this base64 string `/d4OjQAGAgJvToLbkeZ1rQ==` is not meaningful. It can't be decoded to regular characters.